# How do I calculate average potential energy for a given potential 'over a long time'?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, virial-theorem

> A classical particle with total energy $E$ moves under the influence of a potential
>   $$V(x,y)= 3x^3+2x^2y+2y^2x+y^3.$$ 
>   The average potential energy $\langle V \rangle$, calculated over a long time, is equal to?
>
> The options given are $\frac{2E}{3}$,$\frac{E}{3}$, $\frac{2E}{5}$, $\frac{E}{5}$.

I tried solving the Euler-Lagrange for this, but to no avail as i ended up with coupled second order differential equations in $x$ and $y$. I also looked up [Virial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) for this but again it wasn't helpful as I could only find a solution for a simple potential of the form $V=ax^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: $E=\langle T \rangle+\langle V \rangle,$ and 
$ 2\langle T \rangle ~=~ - \langle {\bf r}\cdot {\bf F} \rangle~=~\langle {\bf r}\cdot \frac{\partial V}{\partial {\bf r}}\rangle ~=~3\langle V \rangle .$

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have confusion regarding the potential. But in such situation take the highest power of the equation. That means we have the Euler-Lagrange equation where we can equate $x\cdot \frac{d(V)}{dx}= n\cdot V$. So we get the power of potential as 3 from the given potential function.

Then, accordingly you can use the virial theorem. $E = V + T$ .... So, $T = \frac{1}{2}\left(     x\cdot\frac{d(V)}{dx} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(3V)$.   So, your answer should be third one.

Hope you got it.